# How does a compiler "know" how to translate code into processor specific assembly?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, processor, cpu-architecture

**Stuff that answerers already know, but here it is anyways to show my thinking process:**

Going from HLL to Machine Code, here are rough set of events that takes place (there are Linkers and other things, but let's ignore that for now) :

HLL --> Compiler --> Assembler ----> Machine Code

Depending on what hardware I buy, it may have different Processor (Intel, SPARC, ARM etc.). And Assembly language is Processor specific. So when code goes from Compiler --> Assembler, the Assembly code that gets generated is Processor specific.

**Getting to the point:**

For example: I have Windows OS on my hardware. And I get, say, 'C compiler for Windows 7 64bit'. And I also have Ubuntu on same hardware, and I get 'C compiler for Ubuntu 64 bit'.

1. I can have same OSs on different hardware with different processor architecture, or different OSs on the same hardware (like above example). When I am downloading C compiler, why is it that Compilers are listed as OS specific? Rather than Processor specific? Since the whole point of a compiler is to translate HLL to Assembly, which is Processor Architecture specific and **not** OS specific.
2. Assuming that 1. is how things are done, and when I download a compiler that is for Windows 7 and for Ubuntu, how does the compiler know what processor specific Assembly code to generate? Does the compiler come with various processor specific Assemblers?

Comment: Briefly, the OS provides low level software services, drivers, etc, that the compiler takes advantage of. So the compiler is OS specific. The compiler knows what code to generate because it was simply designed with that knowledge built in. A compiler for x86 architecture, for example, has implicit knowledge built in by the compiler writer of the x86 instruction set.

Comment: I did neglect to mention that when you get into final linking and the format of the executable, clearly the executable format is very OS-specific. The OS interprets the binary executable, determining critical information from the file, and deciding where and how to load and execute the program.

Answer (score 5):

Several factors play into this. For desktop machines, there are practically only two architectures in use: 32 bit is x86 (with various extensions), 64 bit is x86-64. So a lot of software can just ignore this issue and only specify "bitness". This is especially true for Windows prior to Windows RT/8, which don't even try to support any other architectures.

While the compiler has to know about the processor architecture, virtually all interesting programs must interact with the operating system in one way or another. And even if your code doesn't interact with the OS, the compiler has to know which file format to use for binaries, which libraries to link with, and so on. The run-time library is also OS-specific, and commonly bundled with the compiler.

As for how the compiler knows what kind of instructions to generate: Either the binary you downloaded is specifically tailored for one architecture (whether or not the page you got it from mentioned that) and *can't* generate code for other architectures, or it indeed has several backends compiled in.

That said, I don't see a lot of compilers declared "`<language>` compiler for `<operating system>`". Compiler writers are typically much more pedantic in specifying instruction sets, and so are distributors. Only the windows guys are very sloppy with this, because until about a year ago it wasn't useful information.

Answer (score 0):

For actual computations, like adding two numbers, only the hardware matters, and you'll indeed get the same machine code under Windows and under Linux.

The interesting "glue" is provided by platform libraries, e.g. the standard C library, which provides a function for "printing characters on the standard output". The function call code is also determined entirely by the hardware (although there are some conventions which differ between Windows and Linux, such as where to put the function arguments, but those are merely conventions). The interesting platform-specific "meat" is provided by the *implementation* of those libraries. For example, how is `printf` *implemented*? Different code is generated on Linux and Windows, but the differences are not in the *kind* of instructions, but rather in how you talk to the operating system.

Again, this is mostly a matter of convention, and there's no profound difference in the actual machine code of programs for different operating systems on the same hardware. The difference is merely in how you get the operating system to perform certain things on your behalf, things like input/output, giving you memory, telling you the time, etc.